# Accuracy of fine-tuning BERT varied significantly based on epochs for intent classification task

Tags: nlp, word-embedding, bert-language-model

I used `Bert base uncased` as embedding and doing simple cosine similarity for intent classification in my dataset (around `400 classes and 2200 utterances, train:test=80:20`). The base BERT model performs 60% accuracy in the test dataset, but different epochs of fine-tuning gave me quite unpredictable results.

This is my setting:

```
max_seq_length=150
train_batch_size=16
learning_rate=2e-5
```

These are my experiments:

```
base model   accuracy=0.61
epochs=2.0   accuracy=0.30
epochs=5.0   accuracy=0.26
epochs=10.0  accuracy=0.15
epochs=50.0  accuracy=0.20
epochs=75.0  accuracy=0.92
epochs=100.0 accuracy=0.93
```

I don't understand while it behaved like this. I expect that any epochs of fine-tuning shouldn't be worse than the base model because I fine-tuned and inferred on the same dataset. Is there anything I misunderstand or should care about?

Comment: FWIF, i cant even get same accuracy repeated when i run for different epoch count.- same bertbaseuncased. Have raised an issue with huggingface guys  (here)[https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/5863].

Answer (score 2):

Well, generally you'll not be able to feed in all the data in your training set at once (I am assuming you have a huge-dataset that you'll have to use mini-batches). Hence, you split it into mini-batches. So, the accuracy that is displayed is strongly infuluenced a lot by the last mini-batch, or the last training step of the epoch.